# Unable To Download Likes And Comments

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, download, comments, facebook-fql

I use the Facebook API to enable a user to download their data from Facebook, and any likes and comments made on their photos or posts.

On a few occasions customers report that their likes and comments do not download and on a furthur investigation I found that the API is returning an error with the message "Unknown Error". Does anyone know why this happens sometimes to some accounts? I have absolutely no idea.... I have tried using FQL and Open Graph API and still have the same problem, when it happens to a customer it happens for all their likes and comments across their account.

Thanks :)

Comment: Add more debugging code to find out what exactly error code is being returned from facebook.